# JavaScript for-loop to find matching property value stops iterating after the first object

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have a misunderstanding in the way the `for loop` is working in JS… 
for this array:

```
var names = [
  {
    "firstName" : "Tom",
    "LastName"  : "Delavoir"
  },
  {
    "firstName" : "Yop",
    "LastName"  : "laboum"
  },
  {
    "firstName" : "Andrea",
    "LastName"  : "hop"
  }
];
```

This function below is working for the 1st `firstName`, but never checks the next element in my array `names`.

```
function ifExist(firstName, prop){

  for (var i=0; i < names.length; i++) {
    if (firstName == names[i].firstName){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

This will always return `true`,`ifExist("Tom", "LastName");`

But this always return `false`,`ifExist("Yop", "LastName");`

I can get my head around to check all `names[i].firstName` to verify if the first of parameter `ifExist()`  is true or not and not only for the first element of the table…

Comment: your code is checking only firstname; firstName == names[i].firstName) and Tom is first name?

Comment: how you want it to work after `return`?

Comment: oops, ignore prev comment

Comment: wait dont ignore it

Comment: look firstName is property of the object names, you might want to change the code

Comment: Walk through your code with the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return false` *after* the loop has completed, otherwise you will never get past a single iteration through your array. You also used `firstName` as your property every time, instead of using the dynamic string `prop` (which requires that you change `LastName` to `firstName` in your function calls).

```js
var names = [
  {
    "firstName" : "Tom",
    "LastName"  : "Delavoir"
  },
  {
    "firstName" : "Yop",
    "LastName"  : "laboum"
  },
  {
    "firstName" : "Andrea",
    "LastName"  : "hop"
  }
]

function ifExist (value, prop){
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    if (value === names[i][prop]) return true
  }
  return false
}

console.log(ifExist("Tom", "firstName"))

console.log(ifExist("Yop", "firstName"))
```

Comment: Thanks @gyre ! I select this one has the accepted answer, has it correspond to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are returning on the first iteration, giving your loop no chance to loop.

Note that you can use some easier methods to do what you want for example using `some()`

```js
var names = [
  {
    "firstName" : "Tom",
    "LastName"  : "Delavoir"
  },
  {
    "firstName" : "Yop",
    "LastName"  : "laboum"
  },
  {
    "firstName" : "Andrea",
    "LastName"  : "hop"
  }
];

function exists(arr, myName, prop) {
  return arr.some(v => v[prop] === myName);
}


console.log(exists(names, "Yop", "firstName"));
```

Comment: hey this is not bad

Comment: although i cant understand the v[prop] part

Comment: That's bracket notation @Rico. It is used to have a variable as a object's property key - in above case it looks for v.firstName

Comment: No, v holds the object in the current iteration. some() loops over all the objects in the array...

Comment: so hes checking if yop has the property firstName instead of checking if firstname is yop

Comment: oh wait, i got it

Comment: this one was sweet, i gave it plus 1

Comment: is it fastest tho? cos everytime a new object is created and then its property is matched, lets say you have 100k objects and yop was 100k th object, then will this be as fast as other answers?

Comment: There's no new object created @Rico, also it will return after the first match, so I think its speed should be equal

Comment: so as far as i understood it, this will take first object(first iteration) find all properties of this object, match its property if found nice else it will goto second object, and do on till it finds . or does it not find all properties of the object instead only checks if object has property firstName and matches it values, in which case it will be same speed

Comment: looks like it is second case and there is no speed degradation

Comment: Thanks @baao ! It's a very interesting way to do it, and probably cleaner, but in my specific case I'm playing around with the `for loop`.

Answer (score 1):

you are returning true/false in the first iteration and you loop dosent get to run any further. The function returns there itself.
Just remove the else part and return false after the loop.

Comment: Thx  @Pradeep-jain ! Effectively my second `return` was badly positioned !

Answer (score 1):

You are stopping the for loop at first iteration because you have a return in true and false case. You need something like this:

```
function ifExist(firstName, prop){
  for (var i=0; i < names.length; i++) {
    if (firstName === names[i].firstName){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
console.log(ifExist('Tom'))
console.log(ifExist('Yop'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's fix this `function`

```
function ifExist(firstName, prop){

  for (var i=0; i < names.length; i++) {
    if (firstName == names[i].firstName){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

to this

```
function ifExist(search, prop){

  for (var i=0; i < names.length; i++) {
    if (search == names[i][prop]){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

What was fixed:

- you `return`ed whether the first iteration was a match, which is surely what you did not want to `return`. To remedy this I have moved `return false;` after the `for`, so you `return true;` on the first found element and if no element is found, you `return false`
- you had a `prop` parameter, but you never used it. You have checked for `firstName` regardless of `prop`. I fixed this by using `prop` when I check the value

Comment: Thanks @Lajos-arpad ! For the fix and the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

in the first iteration on names array, value of (firstName == names[i].firstName)
is true or or false, and base on the written code in each case function returns , write code as below:

```
    var find=false;
    for (var i=0; i < names.length; i++) {
        if (firstName == names[i].firstName){
             find=true;
             break;
      } 
     }
  return find;
```